# Using plural and singular with "each" before or after

Tags: singular-vs-plural

It seems correct to me to say

> These 5 apples weigh 100g each.

However it also seems correct to say

> Each of these 5 apples weighs 100g.

What is the reasoning behind using the plural in the first, and the singular in the second? They seem to be saying the same thing about an individual apple.

Comment: That's right. They're both correct. And so is _These 5 apples each weigh 100g._ The quantifier _each_ (like _all_; but unike _every_ or _any_) can undergo "Quantifier-shift", which moves _each_ from its original position, quantifying _these 5 apples_, to other positions that are in construction with its focussed constituent (_100g_ here), or immediately before a constituent (like _weigh 100g_ here) that contains the focussed constituent, losing a preposition along the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse the sentences into parts to discover *the subject* and *the predicate*, and remembering that the predicate *has to correspond* to the subject in number and person, you would see that in the sentence

> These 5 apples weigh 100g each.

the subject is "**apples**", *plural*, and the predicate is "**weigh**" (plural): all fine.

In the other sentence

> Each of these 5 apples weighs 100g.

the subject is "**each**", *singular*, and the predicate is "**weighs**" (3rd person singular): all fine.