# "..the following" + plural or singular?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure of the word following should be followed by a plural or singular noun.

Which among these two sentences is grammatically correct?

"Determine the values of q, r, and s so that each of the following equations will be algebraic identities in x."

or

"Determine the values of q, r, and s so that each of the following equation will be algebraic identity in x."

Comment: _Each of_ implies that you are referring to several equations, so why would it not be plural?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Each of them is" or "each of them are"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83127/each-of-them-is-or-each-of-them-are) Also [Each and every one of XYZ + singular / plural Verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131868/each-and-every-one-of-xyz-singular-plural-verb) and [Using plural and singular with “each” before or after](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68411/using-plural-and-singular-with-each-before-or-after) and [We each has/have?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104624/we-each-has-have), among others.

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree. The object complement should be in the singular exactly because we are talking about a single element in a set implied by _each of_.